# Opencv template matching with different size images

Tags: python, opencv

I have two images for comparison when we use the templatematch in opencv. Actually, my requirement is, I have to match the template image - small portion filled with a small string like the one we have in our IDE which I took on 1920x1080 to the complete image which has a 2560X1440 in size.

Please let me know your suggestion.

Ex: consider in ide file icon is my template image in my case. here i have to see that file icon exist or not in the different sized image.